# Printing a string in a boot sector

Tags: assembly, x86-16, qemu, bootloader, bios

I was trying to print a string in a boot sector and have the following code:

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov ah, 0x0e
mov bx, msg
call print

mov bx, msg1
call print

jmp $

print:
        mov al, [bx]
        int 0x10
        inc bx
        cmp al, 0
        jne print
        ret

msg db "hello",0
msg1 db "goodbye",0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

The output using qemu looks like where the underscores are spaces:

```
hello_goodbye_
```

I don't know what I'm missing. The entire point I thought about is to keep looping and printing characters until I find a null character which the strings are terminated with.

I know that I can probably solve the problem with a jump to the end before the bios interrupt call, but I really want to understand why the spaces are being printed after the actual strings.

Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: It's not a space. You print the zero byte because you only check after printing.

Comment: @Jester i got my mistake, i don't know how i missed it. i was comparing against al despite incrementing bx. now, i'm wondering why it won't work when comparing with bx: `cmp bx, 0`. i thought that it should compare the value at bx to the null byte, but it seems to send it into an infinite loop? am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, the brackets. You are comparing the address instead of the value.